# Show that there are infinitely many positive integers $N$ that cannot be written in the form $a^n+b^n+c^n$

Tags: number-theory

> Show that there are infinitely many positive integers $N$ that cannot be written in the form $a^n+b^n+c^n$ where $a,b,c$ are positive integers and $n \geq 2$.

I thought about considering solutions such that $$a^n+b^n+c^n < N^n.$$ Thus $a,b,c < N$. Thus there are less than $N^3$ positive integers expressible in the required form that satisfy the above inequality. Therefore, there are at least $N^n-N^3$ that aren't for a given $n$. I didn't see how to continue from here since the exponent $n$ can vary.

Answer (score 5):

For $n=2$ it is number theoretic, for example it is not possible to represent $8j+7.$

After this we are counting the lattice points with 
$$ a^n + b^n + c^n \leq M. $$

Now that I think of it, for $n=3$ you cannot represent $9j \pm 4.$
For $n=3$ the volume of the convex body is asymptotic to $KM,$ where $K < 1$ is the volume of $N=1.$ Can be written in terms of the Gamma function. A similar argument applies to $a^2 + b^3 + c^6.$

For $n \geq 4$ the volume is $M^{3/n}$ which is strictly smaller, indeed limit is zero density

This is in The Hardy-Littlewood Method by R. C. Vaughan. The 2,3,6 problem is on page 146. I am also on page 146, brief introduction on page 127 ( the second edition for those). [Here is the article being discussed](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Experimental_1995.pdf)

Comment: There are infinitely many positive integers that aren't representable in this form for each $n \geq 2$, but how does that show that there are infinitely many positive integers that aren't representable in the form $a^n+b^n+c^n$?

Comment: @user, The language of the problem is, of course, ambiguous. However, that is an unlikely interpretation for one of your contest/contest preparation problems, as it then becomes a rather large endeavor. Where did you get this one?

Comment: I found it on AoPS.