# Infinitely many numbers not expressible in the form $a^n+b^n+c^n$

Tags: number-theory

> Show that there are infinitely many positive integers $N$ that cannot be written in the form $a^n+b^n+c^n$ where $a,b,c$ are positive integers and $n \geq 2$.

Note that in the question above, $n$ can vary and is not fixed.

I thought about using a modular arithmetic argument by finding a set of values which are not expressible when the exponent is $3n,3n+2,$ or $3n+4$ and then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Note that for all expressions of the form $$a^{3n}+b^{3n}+c^{3n},$$ the numbers which are $4,5,6$ modulo $9$ are not expressible in these forms since each of the terms is $-1,0,1 \pmod{9}$. For expressions of the form $$a^{3n+2}+b^{3n+2}+c^{3n+2} = a^{3n} \cdot a^2+b^{3n} \cdot b^2+c^{3n} \cdot c^2,$$ note that $x^2 \equiv -1,0,1,4 \pmod{9}$ and that $x^3 \equiv -1,0,1 \pmod{9}$. But I couldn't find a set of numbers modulo $9$ which weren't expressible in this form.

For expressions of the form $$a^{3n+4}+b^{3n+4}+c^{3n+4},$$ note that $x^4 \equiv 0,1,3,9 \pmod{13}$ and $x^{3n} \equiv -1,0,1,8 \pmod{13}$. Therefore, $x^{3n+4} \equiv 0,1,3,7,8,9,10,11,12$, but I couldn't find a set of numbers modulo $13$ which weren't expressible in this form.

Can we use a modular arithmetic argument similar to this to solve the cases for $3n+2$ and $3n+4$ one or do we need to use a higher exponent such as $6n$ instead of $3n$?

Comment: Where did your find this problem? As far as I know, already proving that there are infinitely many numbers that cannot be written as a sum of three squares is rather difficult, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Legendre's theorem *characterizes* the numbers which can't be written as a sum of three squares; merely showing that there are infinitely many, though, is quite easy (think mod 8) unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @NoahSchweber In this question, $n$ is allowed to vary and we are considering all such representations of the forms $$a^2+b^2+c^2,a^3+b^3+c^3,a^4+b^4+c^4,\ldots.$$

Comment: @user19405892 Oh, I thought the question was to show that *for each specific $n$*.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: good point, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335309/show-that-there-are-infinitely-many-positive-integers-n-that-cannot-be-written?rq=1

Comment: I just noticed that you asked this exact same question two days ago; reposting questions is extremely frowned upon here. You should edit the original question rather than reposting it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that there are infinitely many positive integers $N$ that cannot be written in the form $a^n+b^n+c^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335309/show-that-there-are-infinitely-many-positive-integers-n-that-cannot-be-written)  That one has a correct answer.  Please unaccept the answer here so it can be deleted.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, but in my other question the answer there was not answering it for all $n$ but for a fixed $n$. I reposted the question to clarify what I meant.

Comment: @user19405892 "I reposted the question to clarify what I meant." *That's not something you should do.* Instead, *edit the original question* to clarify your meaning.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Okay. Would it still be possible to show that $$A_4 \cup A_5 \cup A_6 \cup \cdots$$ has density zero?

Comment: @user19405892 Quite possibly, but not by just showing that each one has density zero. While the union of finitely many density-zero sets has density zero, that's absolutely false for *infinitely many* density-zero sets; I was having a very silly moment.

Comment: See the comments at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273214/prove-that-displaystyle-bigcup-i-4-inftya-i-has-asymptotic-density-ze